# A good way to make zero value meaningful

Tags: go

I have a struct with a int16 in it represent the offset of indexes in a slice. There are 2 states for this value: 1. it can be that the offset is invalid; 2. it's meaningful and will actually represent a positive, negative, or zero value offset. Now the question is that I will allocate an array of this struct, and the default value for this int16 should be the invalid state, but the default value is 0, and 0 can also represent a valid offset with value of 0.

Currently, I use -32768 as the value to represent the invalid state, and manually initialize the array after using `make`. However, I don't like this approach and it doesn't follow the Go way of making the zero value meaningful. Is there a better way to approach this? I don't really want to introduce extra variables as that will take more space in memory.

Comment: You may use a `*int` instead.

Comment: The zero value is what it is. If it's not useful for you or still requires extra initialization, then that's what you need to do. There is no hard requirement that the zero value be a useful starting value, it's just convenient when it works out that way. Many types have constructors, getters and setters for this very reason.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks for the option, but that requires extra space and allocations.

Comment: @JimB In this case the slice might be big and explicit initialization on everything would have some overhead, I'm in a performance critical part.

Comment: Not really. It only requires one extra int.

Comment: @G.M if you don't want any extra fields in the struct, and you don't want to initialize anything, then I'm not sure what you're looking for. You can't change what a zero value is, you can only make use of one when it fits your use case. Perhaps a bigger picture of the problem at hand would reveal a better overall solution, but with limited info there's nothing much to say.

Comment: If you don't want to use a -32768 or another value of int16 to represent the invalid offset I don't think you can do without an extra value. An alternative to using a pointer value is to use an interface type as outlined in my answer, but technically it has the same memory requirements as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Marcus: an interface is twice the size of a pointer, because it requires storing both the dynamic value (usually via a pointer itself) and the dynamic type.

Comment: Just add a `bool` field indicating initialization state see: https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#NullInt16

Comment: @JimB thanks for pointing this out. According to https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/Go115InterfaceSmallInts int16 values are actually stored in value pointer itself. This has the advantage over `*int16` that no allocation is required if but it requires more memory as you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I can store it using an uint16 and offset it with math.minint16. This way the default value 0 is -32768 and is treated as the invalid state, all other numbers are valid.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing the offset value, you can remap the zero value to the invalid constant through addition and subtraction. This will require obscuring the type through a `Get` and `Set`, since accessing the internal value directly will no longer be valid.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Offset struct {
    // This value is not safe to use directly,
    // since it has to be mapped to/from a real offset
    mappedOffset int16
}

const InvalidOffset = -32768

func (o Offset) Get() int16 {
    // Shift values so 0 becomes InvalidOffset
    return o.mappedOffset + InvalidOffset
}

func (o *Offset) Set(i int16) {
    // Shift values so InvalidOffset becomes 0
    o.mappedOffset = i - InvalidOffset
}

func (o Offset) IsValid() bool {
    // Check if it is the actual "Go Zero"
    return o != Offset{}
}

func main() {
    var offset Offset
    fmt.Println("Apparent value:", offset.Get(), "  Internal:", offset, "  IsValid:", offset.IsValid())

    offset.Set(123)
    fmt.Println("Apparent value:", offset.Get(), "  Internal:", offset, "  IsValid:", offset.IsValid())

    offset.Set(InvalidOffset)
    fmt.Println("Apparent value:", offset.Get(), "  Internal:", offset, "  IsValid:", offset.IsValid())
}
```

Output:

```
Apparent value: -32768   Internal: {0}   IsValid: false
Apparent value: 123   Internal: {-32645}   IsValid: true
Apparent value: -32768   Internal: {0}   IsValid: false
```